# Optimizer uses wrong index

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

We have a quite simple select statement accessing data with unique index fields. Nevertheless, the optimizer decides to use a bad index and the selection takes about 4 seconds instead of 0.0x seconds.

This problem doesn't exist with oracle 11g but with oracle 12c.

The table statistics are up to date.

It seems, the estimation for the bad plan is wrong (see below), how can we avoid this?

I guess by adding field statistics or baseline entries, but I hope there is another solution.

Thanks in advance.

**Table Definition**

```
create table PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB(business_unit VARCHAR2(5) not null,
                               ra_cmpgn_wave_id VARCHAR2(15) not null,
                               product_id VARCHAR2(18) not null,
                               cs_aboart_cd VARCHAR2(20) not null,
                               cs_einweis_id VARCHAR2(20) not null,
                               row_added_dttm TIMESTAMP(6),
                               row_added_oprid VARCHAR2(30) not null,
                               row_lastmant_dttm TIMESTAMP(6),
                               row_lastmant_oprid VARCHAR2(30) not null,
                               cs_recstat_xl VARCHAR2(4) not null,
                               /* ... further fields ... */
                               cs_kondition VARCHAR2(20) not null) 
                               tablespace CS_APP pctfree 10 initrans 1 
                               maxtrans 255 storage(initial 40K next 104K
                               minextents 1 maxextents unlimited);
```

**Indexes**

```
create unique index PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB on PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB(
BUSINESS_UNIT,RA_CMPGN_WAVE_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CS_ABOART_CD) 
tablespace PSINDEX pctfree 10 initrans 2 maxtrans 255 
storage(initial 40K next 104K minextents 1 maxextents unlimited);

create index PSBCS_AKT_PROD_TB on PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB(
BUSINESS_UNIT,PRODUCT_ID) 
tablespace PSINDEX pctfree 10 initrans 2 maxtrans 255 
storage(initial 40K next 104K minextents 1 maxextents unlimited);
```

**Table Size**

```
select count(*) from PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB;
--> 6372395
```

**Select Statement**

All required fields of the unique index are given:

```
SELECT CS_STEUERUNG_XL, CS_EWF2EVT
  FROM PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB
 WHERE BUSINESS_UNIT = :1
   AND RA_CMPGN_WAVE_ID = :2
   AND PRODUCT_ID = :3
   AND CS_ABOART_CD = :4;
```

**Execution Details and Explain Plan**

```
select v.CHILD_NUMBER,
       elapsed_time / 1000000 elapsed_time,
       executions,
       round((elapsed_time / decode(executions, 0, 1, executions)) /
             1000000,
             4) elapsed_time_per_exec,
       disk_reads,
       buffer_gets,
       rows_processed,
       cpu_time
  from v$sql v
 where v.SQL_ID = 'dqrktmcraprvp';

  /*
  CHILD_NUMBER  ELAPSED_TIME  EXECUTIONS  ELAPSED_TIME_PER_EXEC DISK_READS  BUFFER_GETS ROWS_PROCESSED  CPU_TIME
  0             400,874709    100         4,0087                98457       495295      86              5929096
  1             0,017217      8           0,0022                2           36          4               2108
  2             0,002038      2           0,001                 0           9           1               0
  */

 select plan_table_output
 from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor('dqrktmcraprvp', 0)) t;

 /*
    SQL_ID  dqrktmcraprvp, child number 0
    -------------------------------------
    SELECT CS_STEUERUNG_XL, CS_EWF2EVT FROM PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB WHERE 
    BUSINESS_UNIT = :1 AND RA_CMPGN_WAVE_ID = :2 AND PRODUCT_ID = :3 AND 
    CS_ABOART_CD = :4

    Plan hash value: 1118713352

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                           | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |                   |       |       |     1 (100)|          |
    |*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB |     1 |    46 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | PSBCS_AKT_PROD_TB |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
    ---------------------------------------------------

       1 - filter(("RA_CMPGN_WAVE_ID"=:2 AND "CS_ABOART_CD"=:4))
       2 - access("BUSINESS_UNIT"=:1 AND "PRODUCT_ID"=:3)     */ 


 select plan_table_output
 from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor('dqrktmcraprvp', 1)) t;

    /*

    SQL_ID  dqrktmcraprvp, child number 1
    -------------------------------------
    SELECT CS_STEUERUNG_XL, CS_EWF2EVT FROM PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB WHERE 
    BUSINESS_UNIT = :1 AND RA_CMPGN_WAVE_ID = :2 AND PRODUCT_ID = :3 AND 
    CS_ABOART_CD = :4

    Plan hash value: 619225732

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                   | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                   |       |       |     1 (100)|          |
    |   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB |     1 |    46 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
    ---------------------------------------------------

       2 - access("BUSINESS_UNIT"=:1 AND "RA_CMPGN_WAVE_ID"=:2 AND "PRODUCT_ID"=:3 AND 
                  "CS_ABOART_CD"=:4)

    */
```

**Amendment (see comments)**

Field values of PROCUCT_ID are unequally distributed

```
OCCURENCE_OF_PRODUCT_ID TOTAL
upto 10^1-1             1134
upto 10^2-1             1607
upto 10^3-1             1649
upto 10^4-1             455
upto 10^5-1             279
```

**Output of dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null, null, '+OUTLINE')**

upto 37 seconds:

```
    SQL_ID  ga79yhh54r5bu, child number 0
    -------------------------------------
    select a.cs_ewf2evt, a.cs_steuerung_xl from ps_cs_akt_prod_tb a where 
    a.business_unit = :1 and a.ra_cmpgn_wave_id = :2 and a.product_id = :3 
    and a.cs_aboart_cd = :4

    Plan hash value: 1118713352

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                           | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |                   |       |       |     1 (100)|          |
    |*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB |     1 |    46 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | PSBCS_AKT_PROD_TB |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Outline Data
    -------------

      /*+
          BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
          IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
          OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('12.1.0.2')
          DB_VERSION('12.1.0.2')
          OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_max_permutations' 50)
          OPT_PARAM('_unnest_subquery' 'false')
          OPT_PARAM('optimizer_dynamic_sampling' 4)
          OPT_PARAM('_gby_hash_aggregation_enabled' 'false')
          OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_use_feedback' 'false')
          OPT_PARAM('_px_adaptive_dist_method' 'off')
          OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_dsdir_usage_control' 0)
          OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_adaptive_plans' 'false')
          OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_strans_adaptive_pruning' 'false')
          OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_gather_feedback' 'false')
          OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_nlj_hj_adaptive_join' 'false')
          OPT_PARAM('optimizer_index_cost_adj' 20)
          ALL_ROWS
          OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$1")
          INDEX_RS_ASC(@"SEL$1" "A"@"SEL$1" ("PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB"."BUSINESS_UNIT" 
                  "PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB"."PRODUCT_ID"))
          BATCH_TABLE_ACCESS_BY_ROWID(@"SEL$1" "A"@"SEL$1")
          END_OUTLINE_DATA
      */

    Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
    ---------------------------------------------------

       1 - filter(("A"."RA_CMPGN_WAVE_ID"=:2 AND "A"."CS_ABOART_CD"=:4))
       2 - access("A"."BUSINESS_UNIT"=:1 AND "A"."PRODUCT_ID"=:3)
```

~ 0.06 seconds

```
    SQL_ID  ga79yhh54r5bu, child number 0
    -------------------------------------
    select a.cs_ewf2evt, a.cs_steuerung_xl from ps_cs_akt_prod_tb a where 
    a.business_unit = :1 and a.ra_cmpgn_wave_id = :2 and a.product_id = :3 
    and a.cs_aboart_cd = :4

    Plan hash value: 619225732

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                   | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                   |       |       |     1 (100)|          |
    |   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB |     1 |    46 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Outline Data
    -------------

      /*+
          BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
          IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
          OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('12.1.0.2')
          DB_VERSION('12.1.0.2')
          OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_max_permutations' 50)
          OPT_PARAM('_unnest_subquery' 'false')
          OPT_PARAM('optimizer_dynamic_sampling' 4)
          OPT_PARAM('_gby_hash_aggregation_enabled' 'false')
          OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_use_feedback' 'false')
          OPT_PARAM('_px_adaptive_dist_method' 'off')
          OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_dsdir_usage_control' 0)
          OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_adaptive_plans' 'false')
          OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_strans_adaptive_pruning' 'false')
          OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_gather_feedback' 'false')
          OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_nlj_hj_adaptive_join' 'false')
          OPT_PARAM('optimizer_index_cost_adj' 20)
          ALL_ROWS
          OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$1")
          INDEX_RS_ASC(@"SEL$1" "A"@"SEL$1" ("PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB"."BUSINESS_UNIT" 
                  "PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB"."RA_CMPGN_WAVE_ID" "PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB"."PRODUCT_ID" 
                  "PS_CS_AKT_PROD_TB"."CS_ABOART_CD"))
          END_OUTLINE_DATA
      */

    Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
    ---------------------------------------------------

       2 - access("A"."BUSINESS_UNIT"=:1 AND "A"."RA_CMPGN_WAVE_ID"=:2 AND 
                  "A"."PRODUCT_ID"=:3 AND "A"."CS_ABOART_CD"=:4)
```

Comment: maybe this can be a help: https://carlos-sierra.net/2013/02/28/how-to-flush-one-cursor-out-of-the-shared-pool/ with the option to pin a specific execution plan: https://github.com/carlos-sierra/cscripts/blob/master/sql/spm/create_spb_from_cur.sql

Comment: @valentin Thanks, I'm looking for a solution to fix this problem without manually loading all problematic plans to baseline. I hope there exists a more general approach to solve it.

Comment: @BobC It strongly depends on bind values. In some rare cases, both plans should be nearly equal. Values of `PRODUCT_ID` are unequaly distributed, see my addition

Comment: or you can try to disable BATCHED table access, set the parameter `_optimizer_batch_table_access_by_rowid`  to `FALSE`.  More information: https://www.pythian.com/blog/batched-table-access/ .  Or disable using  a hint `SELECT /*+ NO_BATCH_TABLE_ACCESS_BY_ROWID(i)*/ `

Comment: Can you run the following after each statement and post the output: select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor( null, null, '+OUTLINE' ) )

Comment: @BobC I've added the output.

Comment: OK, humor me on this. Can you rename the index PSBCS_AKT_PROD_TB to APSBCS_AKT_PROD_TB. Then try your queries :)

Comment: @valentin setting the parameter `_optimizer_batch_table_access_by_rowid` does not have any effect.

Comment: Since they are unequally distributed, check for histograms: select owner, table_name, column_name, histogram, num_buckets  from dba_tab_col_statistics where owner = :owner and table_name = :tablename;  12c has  several improvements to histograms including the new HYBRID histogram type: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_histo.htm#TGSQL366.  You can regather just histogram stats via something like: EXEC dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('OWNER','TABLE', method_opt=>'for all columns size skewonly', cascade => true, degree=>2);

Comment: @BobC Same results with renamed Index :-)

Comment: Are you doing anything to force a hard parse between these tests? eg, changing the query text with a comment, or flushing the shared pool?

Comment: @BobC Yes, I do. I'm adding a unique comment in the sql statement.

Comment: There are a lot of hidden and unusual parameters here.  I wonder what `optimizer_index_cost_adj` is doing to the plans.  Both of them would likely be relatively small to begin with.  I wonder if then multiplying them by 0.2 means that they both go under 1 and the optimizer thinks they are the same cost.

Comment: @JonHeller I agree, there are a lot of hidden parameters and i guess it is optimizable. :-)  As far as I understand the `optimizer_index_cost_adj` parameter, the value of 0.2 means the optimizer is forced to prefer the index over the full table scan? "For example, a setting of 50 makes the index access path look half as expensive as normal." see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams144.htm#REFRN10143

Answer (score 1):

Values of `PRODUCT_ID` field are unequaly distributed (see list of distribution in my question above).

Therefore in some rare cases, both plans are nearly equal. Because the statement is called with bind variables, the estimation is processed only at the first execution.

With

```
alter session set "_optim_peek_user_binds"=false;
```

the optimizer is forced to reevaluate the bind values at second execution.

Comment: Did you build the histograms as suggested by Kris-Johnson? I would have expected the cursor to become bind sensitive / bind aware.

Comment: @BobC No, I didn't rebuild/change the histograms. At first execution, the optimizer decided to use an appropriate index according to the field statistics of `PRODUCT_ID`. The problem was the reusage of this execution plan with other bind values of `PRODUCT_ID´ (with completly different statistics).